# Why is Excel removing conditional formatting created in R?

Tags: r, excel, conditional-formatting

I am using R to conditional shade cells within an .xlsx document. The R code runs smoothly with no errors and creates my .xlsx document ok. However, when I go to open the .xlsx file with Excel, Excel states that:

"We found a problem with some content in {file name} Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can?".

I select 'Yes' and the file opens with no shading included and a window appears saying:

"Removed Feature: Conditional formatting from /xl/worksheets/sheet7.xml part".

It appears that my R code is working and applying conditional formatting but then Excel is removing it for some reason.

Here is my R code:

```
data_output_root = paste0(project_root, "/Output/2022/NI Table 3 SOC2/")

data_template_root = paste0(project_root, "/Template/2022/NI Table 3 SOC2/")

 

new_workbook <- loadWorkbook(paste0(data_template_root, "Occupation SOC20 (2) Table 3 (NI).1   Weekly pay - Gross 2022.xlsx"))

 

# Read in xls file that data will come from

data_from_xlsCV <- read_xls(paste0(data_input_root, "Work Region Occupation SOC20 (2) NI Table 3 (NI).1b   Weekly pay - Gross 2022 CV.xls"), sheet = "Male")

 

selected_data <- data_from_xlsCV[6:41, 2:17]

 

selected_data <- sapply(selected_data, as.numeric)

 

selected_data <-format(selected_data, nsmall= 1)

 

# Write selected data into selected workbook

writeData(new_workbook, sheet = "Table3.1b Male CV",

          x = selected_data,

          startRow = 10, startCol = 2,

          colNames = FALSE)

 

# Create and apply formatting

cvFive <- createStyle(bgFill = "#5bc0de",

                      numFmt = "#,###.#",

                      halign = "right",

                      fontSize = 12)

 

cvTen <- createStyle(bgFill = "#428bca",

                     numFmt = "#,###.#",

                     halign = "right",

                     fontSize = 12)

 

conditionalFormatting(new_workbook, sheet = "Table3.1b Male CV",

                      rows = 10:45, cols = 3:17,

                      rule = "between", operator = c(5,9),

                      style = cvFive)

 

conditionalFormatting(new_workbook, sheet = "Table3.1b Male CV",

                      rows = 10:45, cols = 3:17,

                      rule = "between", operator = c(10,20),

                      style = cvTen)

 

# Save new workbook to Output folder

saveWorkbook(new_workbook, paste0(data_output_root,"Occupation SOC20 (2) Table 3 (NI).1   Weekly pay - Gross 2022.xlsx"), overwrite = TRUE)
```

I am using Excel version 2306 from Microsoft 365 Apps.

I have not known what to try in order to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using openXLSX here (for future reference, it's helpful to include what packages you're using). If you check out the [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/openxlsx.pdf) for openXLSX you can find a number of examples of how to use the conditional formatting function on pg 16. There's no operator argument, instead you'd need something like this:

```
conditionalFormatting(new_workbook, sheet = "Table3.1b Male CV",
                      rows = 10:45, cols = 3:17, 
                      type = "between", 
                      rule = c(5,9), 
                      style = cvFive)
```

It's worth noting that just because R runs the code without error, doesn't mean it's working correctly, especially with OpenXLSX where certain actions aren't happening until you open the file - this may be why you found it hard to troubleshoot this.